# How to add a property to a node?

Tags: python, networkx, tweepy

I have been trying to add a property like name to this node I am creating but getting error message.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeQL5.png)

```
    # add name as a property to each node
    # with networkX each node is a dictionary
    G.add_node(tweeter_id,'name' = tweeter_name)
    G.add_node(interact_id,'name' = interact_name)
```

This is the error I get.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL2dt.png)

```
      File "<ipython-input-31-55b9aecd990d>", line 28
        G.add_node(tweeter_id,'name' = tweeter_name)
                              ^
    SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

For reference this is the whole code:

```
import networkx as nx

# define an empty Directed Graph
# A directed graph is a graph where edges have a direction
# in our case the edges goes from user that sent the tweet to
# the user with whom they interacted (retweeted, mentioned or quoted)
#g = nx.Graph()
G = nx.DiGraph()

# loop over all the tweets and add edges if the tweet include some interactions
for tweet in tweet_list:
    # find all influencers in the tweet
    tweeter, interactions = getAllInteractions(tweet)
    tweeter_id, tweeter_name = tweeter
    tweet_id = getTweetID(tweet)
    
    # add an edge to the Graph for each influencer
    for interaction in interactions:
        interact_id, interact_name = interaction
        
        # add edges between the two user ids
        # this will create new nodes if the nodes are not already in the network
        # we also add an attribute the to edge equal to the id of the tweet
        G.add_edge(tweeter_id, interact_id, tweet_id=tweet_id)
        
        # add name as a property to each node
        # with networkX each node is a dictionary
        G.add_node(tweeter_id, tweeter_name)
        G.add_node(interact_id, interact_name)
```

Comment: Please don't post links to images. Copy/paste the plain text directly to your question. People mostly don't waste their time to follow links, they want to see all you question at once.

Comment: It says I am still new on stack so I can't embed yet.

Comment: There you go. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read from [the documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_node.html#networkx.Graph.add_node)

> Use keywords set/change node attributes:
>
> ```
> >>> G.add_node(1,size=10)
>
> >>> G.add_node(3,weight=0.4,UTM=('13S',382871,3972649))
> ```

So use a keyword argument `name` to define the attribute.
(NOTE: **Without the Quotes**, otherwise it would be a `str` and would cause the `SyntaxError` you're facing since it's an assignment to a string literal)

Do something like this:

```
    # add name as a property to each node
    # with networkX each node is a dictionary
    G.add_node(tweeter_id, name = tweeter_name)
    G.add_node(interact_id, name = interact_name)
```

and it should work

Comment: Thank you. This was it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `add_node` is a function. And you can't assing a value to a function.

You're doing it when you try:

```py
G.add_node(tweeter_id, 'name') = tweeter_name
```

**UPD**: since you are using the networkx library, you can take a look at their documentation for the add_node function [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_node.html)

I believe what you want to do is:

```py
G.add_node(tweeter_id, attr_dict={'name': tweeter_name})
```

or as Tibebes. M pointed out, you can also do:

```py
G.add_node(tweeter_id, name=tweeter_name)
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you. I am trying to assign 'name' =  tweeter_name. I realized I wrote it wrong in the code I posted above because of the parenthesis. But I am trying o add 'name; as tweeter_name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your

```
G.add_node(tweeter_id,'name') = tweeter_name
G.add_node(interact_id,'name') = interact_name
```

use

```
G.add_node(tweeter_id, tweeter_name)
G.add_node(interact_id, interact_name)
```

(supposing that you have assigned some strings to your variables `tweeter_name` and `interact_name`).